# PHP Mysql PayPal IPN Not Updating Database

Tags: php, mysql

I'm using paypals IPN for players to purchase points from my game. Once they purchase them it should update the users table where their Id is and give them points and energy, and then insert into a different table named transactions. I've tested it and the IPN is sending but it's not updating the database or inserting into the table. Here's the code:

```
    <?php session_start() ?>
    <?php require 'connect.php' ?>
    <?php
    // check if logged into PsychoWars
    if(!$id) {
        die('Error: Not Logged In! Contact Us With The Transaction ID!'); 
    }
    // STEP 1: read POST data
    // Reading POSTed data directly from $_POST causes serialization issues with array data in the POST.
    // Instead, read raw POST data from the input stream.
    $raw_post_data = file_get_contents('php://input');
    $raw_post_array = explode('&', $raw_post_data);
    $myPost = array();
    foreach ($raw_post_array as $keyval) {
    $keyval = explode ('=', $keyval);
    if (count($keyval) == 2)
    $myPost[$keyval[0]] = urldecode($keyval[1]);
    }
    // read the IPN message sent from PayPal and prepend 'cmd=_notify-validate'
    $req = 'cmd=_notify-validate';
    if(function_exists('get_magic_quotes_gpc')) {
    $get_magic_quotes_exists = true;
    }
    foreach ($myPost as $key => $value) {
    if($get_magic_quotes_exists == true && get_magic_quotes_gpc() == 1) {
    $value = urlencode(stripslashes($value));
    } else {
    $value = urlencode($value);
    }
    $req .= "&$key=$value";
    }
    // STEP 2: POST IPN data back to PayPal to validate
    $ch = curl_init('https://sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $req);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Connection: Close'));
    // In wamp-like environments that do not come bundled with root authority certificates,
    // please download 'cacert.pem' from "http://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html" and set
    // the directory path of the certificate as shown below:
    // curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, dirname(__FILE__) . '/cacert.pem');
    if( !($res = curl_exec($ch)) ) {
    // error_log("Got " . curl_error($ch) . " when processing IPN data");
    curl_close($ch);
    exit;
    }
    curl_close($ch);
    // STEP 3: Inspect IPN validation result and act accordingly
    if (strcmp ($res, "VERIFIED") == 0) {
    // The IPN is verified, process it:
    // check whether the payment_status is Completed (Done)
    // check that txn_id has not been previously processed ()
    // check that receiver_email is your Primary PayPal email (Done)
    // check that payment_amount/payment_currency are correct (Done)
    // process the notification
    // assign posted variables to local variables
    $item_name = $_POST['item_name'];
    $item_number = $_POST['item_number'];
    $payment_status = $_POST['payment_status'];
    $payment_amount = $_POST['mc_gross'];
    $payment_currency = $_POST['mc_currency'];
    $txn_id = $_POST['txn_id'];
    $receiver_email = $_POST['receiver_email'];
    $payer_email = $_POST['payer_email'];
    // Checking if package exists
    $get_points = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM buying_offers WHERE id=".$item_number."");
    if(mysql_num_rows($get_points) == 0) {
        die('Error: Boss Point Offer Doesn\'t Exist!');
    }
    // Get Points Info
    $points_info = mysql_fetch_array($get_points);
    $points_cost = $points_info['cost'];
    $points_amount = $points_info['points'];
    $points_energy = $points_info['energy'];
    $points_name = $points_info['package'];

    // check that payment_amount/payment_currency are correct
    if($payment_amount != $points_cost) {
        die('Error: Payment Doesn\'t Equal Package Cost!');
    }
    if($receiver_email != 'bad.karma12323@gmail.com') {
        die('Error: Paypal Email Doesn\'t Match!');
    }
    // checking payment status
    if($payment_status == 'Completed'){
        echo 'Success: You Were Rewarded '.$points_amount.' Boss Points And '.$points_energy.' Energy!';
        $update_user = mysql_query("UPDATE users SET points=(points+".$points_amount."),energy=(energy+".$points_energy.") WHERE id=".$id."");
        $add_trans = mysql_query("INSERT INTO transactions (user_id,txn_id,item_name,payment_status,cost,time) VALUES ('$id','$txn_id','$points_name','$payment_status','$payment_amount','".time()."')");
    }
    elseif($payment_status == 'Denied' || $payment_status == 'Failed' || $payment_status == 'Refunded' || $payment_status == 'Reversed' || $payment_status == 'Voided'){
        die('Error: There Was An Issue With The Transaction!');
    }
    elseif($payment_status == 'In-Progress' || $payment_status == 'Pending' || $payment_status == 'Processed'){
        //Do something
    }
    elseif($payment_status == 'Canceled_Reversal'){
        die('Error: The Transaction Was Cancelled!');
    }
    // IPN message values depend upon the type of notification sent.
    // To loop through the &_POST array and print the NV pairs to the screen:
    foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
    echo $key." = ". $value."<br>";
    }
    } else if (strcmp ($res, "INVALID") == 0) {
    // IPN invalid, log for manual investigation
    echo "The response from IPN was: <b>" .$res ."</b>";
    }
    echo mysql_error();
    ?>
```

The IPN Message from paypal shows all of the variables going through, but like I said, Nothing's updating. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: var_dump your $payment_status, maybe it's not shown as completed

Comment: I recommend using [this PayPal IPN library](https://github.com/Quixotix/PHP-PayPal-IPN), it's extremely useful for this.

Comment: You said there was no update, but is there a new entry in the transactions table ?

Comment: @chikamtsu It doesn't insert into the transactions table either.